# css hover is not working in this code

Tags: html, css, hover

I am using an input text, this input text is fired a datepicker() functionwhen it clicks.

I want to make a message when the user hover over this input text.

I tried this

#### css

```
#CldrFrom:hover:after{
    background: #333;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 26px;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(messageHint);
    left: 20%;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 98;
    width: 220px;
}

#CldrFrom:hover:before{
    border: solid;
    border-color: #333 transparent;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
    bottom: 20px;
    content: "";
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

#### html

```
<input type="text" id="CldrFrom" placeholder="From" style="width:15%" messageHint="From" />
```

When I hover over the input text. nothing happens

why please?

#### note

the input text is hidden when the page loads but then I make it appears using jquery in a button. but Idon't think that could make the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Input` elements can't have pseudo elements. You'll need to use another DOM element if you need to apply this effect.

Comment: there should be a solution.

Comment: @user3432257 there probably is, but it's not Anon's responsibility to find it, necessarily. He answered your question "why" accurately.

Comment: @TylerH yes I know. and I hope someone to give me another solution to that.

Comment: wrap your input in a `div` or `p` and use the wrapper's ::pseudo

Comment: you can wrap the necessary elements in divs and using JS for transfer the desired attributes

Comment: @enapupe I tried to use `span` but still not working

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
a:hover
{
background-color:#f00;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<a href="http://www.wikipedia.org">Hover effect</a>

<p><b>Note:</b> The :hover selector style links on mouse-over.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.change{
background-color:#0ff}
.change:hover
{
background-color:#ccc;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a class="change" href="#">Example</a>
</body>
</html>
```